# Best way to bulk update stock and price for 50+ thousands of products?

Tags: price, import, stock, magmi

We have well over a hundred thousand products in our magento CE 1.9.2.4. Many are drop shipped from a number of suppliers. Several suppliers can provide the same product. Naturally they will all have different stock and provide different pricing. Anyone has a custom script that parses all the feeds from all the suppliers and create a single feed that contains the new stock and pricing for all the products? With this volume of products what importer we should use -magmi or store manager or something else? For product content(image, description etc) what should we do - take etilize/icecat (full or open) paid service or web scraping? We also like to have live stock & price update via xml since our supplier also supports xml live update. We also want order, RMA integration with our suppliers through xml. Is there any one can help us to move to the right direction?

Waited for answer, but no response. So, here is project. Anyone can complete the project with pay, please contact us

Project: Integration with Distributors and Product Content Provider Etilize

Main Task:

1. Download the distributors (currently 3 distributor) flat file from their respective ftp site to our server. Daily basis. Automation through crone job. Also able to import manually. 
   Sub-Task: At admin panel there should be Top Menu like Focaas Distributors>Manage Distributors. Clicking Manage Distributors will open up grid. Able to add as many distributor by clicking "Add Distributor Button" at the top. Open up form will have text field to input both ftp and xml credentials. After save it will go back to grid view. Grid view column will include Name of Distributor, Downloaded at, Imported At, Total Product, In Stock, Action. Under Action column Edit button will be there in order to modify the ftp & xml credentials if needed
2. Import above those data to database. Daily basis. Automation through crone job. Also able to import manually to database
3. Download product content data from Etilize to the server and  then import those to the database. Daily Basis. This task has ALREADY BEEN COMPLETED. Mentioned just for reference.
4. Process above all data sets through mysql query (mostly joining) and make a single csv file ready to import for magento via magmi
5. Configure Magmi for Price & Special Price and others.
6. At the admin panel on Product edit tab, there will be a tab called Supplier. This tab will have a table. It will include the columns named Supplier, Stock, Price and Supplier SKU. The table will show each suppliers info for that particular product. At the bottom of the table or the top there should be a button called Update. Hitting the update button it will update stock, price and supplier sku through xml request. We have a script. We can share that.
7. Order Entry and Tracking automation for all 3 distributors. We will purchase xtento extension. All you need to write an xml script. We will provide the xml guide link/pdf file given by our distributors.
8. Might need to customize media.phtml file in order to adapt image url